# C++ & varargs with different compilers

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, variadic-functions

I'm trying to recompile a C++ project written with GCC to clang and it gives me some problems with varargs method.

**NB**: The project should compile also with non c++-11 compliant compilers, so I cannot use here fancy C++11 syntaxes..

GCC accepts without warnings the following code (1):

```
void Set(TreeIter &it, ...) {
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, it);
    gtk_list_store_set_valist(*this, const_cast<TreeIter *>(&it), va);
    va_end(va);
}
```

and (2):

```
void AddTail(...) {
    TreeIter it;
    gtk_list_store_append(*this, &it);
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, this);
    gtk_list_store_set_valist(*this, &it, va);
    va_end(va);
}
```

While CLANG emits a warning on both:

(1):

```
 ./ootree.h:444:30: warning: 'va_start' has undefined behavior with reference types [-Wvarargs]
```

(2):

```
 ./ootree.h:476:30: warning: second parameter of 'va_start' not last named argument [-Wvarargs]
```

I can easily fix (1) by replacing the TreeIter reference with a copy (and the standard seems to require me to do so), but I don't find an easy way to fix (2), here is a minimal standalone example showing the behaviour, and this program WORKS not only with gcc but also with clang, but those warning are quite scaring...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

struct T {
    void print(...) {
        va_list va;
        va_start(va, this);
        vprintf("%d %d %d\n", va);
        va_end(va);
    }
};

int main() {
    T().print(2, 4, 6);
}
```

Comment: Clang is right. See  [support.runtime]/3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution to (2) would be to take the first 2 arguments explicitly, possibly providing a 1-argument overload:

```
void AddTail(gint column, GValue *value, ...) {
    TreeIter it;
    gtk_list_store_append(*this, &it);
    gtk_list_store_set_value(*this, &it, column, value);
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, value);
    gtk_list_store_set_valist(*this, &it, va);
    va_end(va);
}

void AddTail(gint column) {
    TreeIter it;
    gtk_list_store_append(*this, &it);
    assert(column == -1);
}
```

Comment: I've used a slightly modified version with a template parameter instead of a GValue but this solved my problem, thanks :)

Comment: @Jarod42 `gtk_list_store_set_valist` takes a sentinel (`-1`), so there is always at least one argument.

Answer (score 1):

You may change (2) to

```
static void AddTail(T* that, ...) {
    TreeIter it;
    gtk_list_store_append(*that, &it);
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, that);
    gtk_list_store_set_valist(*that, &it, va);
    va_end(va);
}
```

and change the calls from `T().print(2, 4, 6);` to `T::print(T(), 2, 4, 6);`.

or even add a dummy tag at first parameter:

```
struct variadic_tag {};

void AddTail(variadic_tag, ...) {
    TreeIter it;
    gtk_list_store_append(*that, &it);
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, that);
    gtk_list_store_set_valist(*that, &it, va);
    va_end(va);
}
```

and change `T().print(2, 4, 6);` to `T().print(variadic_tag{}, 2, 4, 6);`.